# Grid with sub-grids using slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, grid, slickgrid

I've got a project that requires me to use a grid that supports sub-grids. From what I can tell, jqGrid supports it, but slickgrid does not. If that's not the case, I haven't found any examples of sub-grids using slickgrid. Does anyone know if that's possible to do in Slickgrid?

Comment: Slick grid has expand and collapse feature which can be used as a sub-grid.

Comment: @emphaticsunshine I assume you're talking about something along the lines of this example: http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping. If so, that's not really a sub-grid. I'm talking about a grid with different columns than the root.

Comment: Not sure how helpful this will be without examples, but I've managed to set up two grids on screen and simply filter the second one based on the selection in the first. Basically, feed one or multiple values from the selected row to a filter on the second grid.

Comment: actually I was referring to this example : http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html

Comment: Another grid  with row virtualization in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20877427/1060656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it really doesn't support this.

Comment: Is this still not supported?