# Creating a Table Using Closure Tools

Tags: google-closure-library

Can anyone help me in creating a table(grid layout) using closure Libray?
Is there any widget available for it? I searched but din't find any!
Please Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of May 2012, the Closure Library does not provide a table/grid layout component.

There is a table sorter (see [demo](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/tablesorter.html)), but it only decorates traditional HTML tables.

You might also want to take a look at the [Visualization Table](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table), which is part of Google Chart Tools.

See the [discussion on support for table/grid components in the Closure Library](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/closure-library-discuss/table%2420grid/closure-library-discuss/x1afFp9Y1Ho/31xhS792UT0J).

Answer (score 3):

Grid written in Google Closure  - http://dekajp.github.io/demos/index.html

Source : https://github.com/dekajp/google-closure-grid

- Data Virtualization ~ 100,000 Rows
- Alternate Row Highlight
- Active Cell and Active Row Highlight
- Sorting
- Column Resizing & Move
- Paging
- Editing
- Frozen Columns
- Subgrid / Hierarchical Display

**disclaimer** : I am author of this grid . The code is currently under active development.